# Mounted external drive, samba shared directory, authentication problems with win 10 viewing

Tags: mount, samba

I've added a line to fstab to mount external drive.

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=5c32fc0d-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=5c32fc0d-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=C632D59E32D593B1 /plex ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,nofail,umask=007,user 0 0
```

Drive mounts fine but I'm trying to setup a Samba share on the same folder.

smb.conf extract

```
[plex]
path = /plex
writeable = yes
guest only = yes
public = yes
```

I can see the share from win 10 but if I access it windows gives me an error saying "you do not have permission to access \192.168.0.36\plex"

If I setup a share on another folder thats not a mounted directory win 10 has no trouble seeing the contents.

If I run ls-l on the folder I can see that the permissions are set thus

```
drwxrwx---   1 pi   pi   20480 Jan 24 17:52 plex
```

I've tried

```
sudo chown 777 /plex
```

but the permissions stay the same.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `chown 777` - you've set the userid to 777, and haven't touched the permissions ... did you mean `chmod 777`?

Comment: Doh.... Keep getting caught out with permissions. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally sorted it. Found a great article on the plex website [about mounting ntfs drives](https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288606-mounting-ntfs-drives-on-linux/). Add the option "permissions" to the fstab and it let me change the permissions once mounted, that let the samba share work.

Comment: I do not understand how to set an option **permissions**. Can you please explain a bit more in detail, maybe with an example? Do you have a link to the great article?

Comment: Here you go. https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288606-mounting-ntfs-drives-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your fstab to `UUID=C632D59E32D593B1 /plex ntfs defaults 0 2` when I've been setting up smb drives in the past I had similar issues and it's been a case of the drive not mounting with the correct permissions on boot. The above ntfs defaults 0 2 is currently working for me using a pi as a nas. Hope that helps. :)